# Error en Laravel [Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 10000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0]

Tags: php, laravel

Hasta el momento solo la he probado con 9 empleados y no tengo ningún problema, pero cuando intento agregar un numero mas grande y por grande hablo de mas de 500 me sale el error mencionado en el titulo de este post. Antes de continuar, debo aclarar que ya he leído sobre el error y se que se puede evitar editando el archivo php.ini y aumentando la cantidad de variables  máximas pero no estoy seguro de que esta sea la solución mas adecuada ya que no siempre podre tener acceso al archivo php.ini como por ejemplo en un hosting compartido. Mi pregunta es: ¿de que manera puedo “empaquetar” o “enviar” mis datos de tal forma que no sean N numero de variables sino algo menos agresivo con el servidor o que no haga uso de tantas variables?

**Mi código es el siguiente:**

1. El form es principalmente un bucle foreach que crea una tabla con los nombres de los empleados desde la base de datos y los cálculos necesarios (Sin agregar todas las filas que realmente tiene sería algo mas o menos así)

```html
<form action="{{ route('nomina.store') }}" method="POST" id="calcular-nomina">
        @csrf
            <input 
                style="width: 127px" 
                type="date" 
                class="form-control form-control-sm mb-1" 
                id="fecha_inicial" 
                name="fecha_inicial"
                editcheck="req=Y=Por favor seleccione una fecha inicial"
            >

            <input 
                style="width: 127px" 
                type="date" 
                class="form-control form-control-sm mb-3" 
                id="fecha_final" 
                name="fecha_final"
                editcheck="req=Y=Por favor seleccione una fecha final"
            >
            <ul>
                <li class="text-left">{{"SMMLV = " . '$' . number_format($configuration->smmlv,0,',','.') }}</li>
                <li class="text-left">{{"Subsidio de transporte = " . '$' . number_format($configuration->subsidio_transporte,0,',','.') }}</li>
                <li class="text-left">{{"Total = " . '$' . number_format(($configuration->smmlv+$configuration->subsidio_transporte),0,',','.') }}</li>
            </ul>

            <table id="tabla-empleados" class="table table-sm" style="font-size:12px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="bg-info text-center align-middle" scope="col">NOMBRE EMPLEADO</th>
                        <th class="bg-info text-center align-middle" scope="col" hidden>ID</th>
                        <th class="bg-info text-center align-middle" scope="col">DIAS LABORADOS</th>
                        <th class="bg-info text-center align-middle" scope="col">PORCENTAJE AUMENTO</th>
                        <th class="bg-info text-center align-middle" scope="col">BÁSICO</th>
                        <th class="bg-primary text-center align-middle" scope="col">HORAS EXTRAS DIURNAS</th>
                        <th class="bg-primary text-center align-middle" scope="col">TOTAL HORAS EXTRAS DIURNAS</th>
                        
                        <th class="bg-info text-center align-middle" scope="col">TOTAL</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($employees as $employee)
                  <tr>
                    <td class="text-left align-middle">
                        <a href="">{{ mb_convert_case($employee->name, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8") }}</a>
                    </td>

                    <td class="text-center align-middle" hidden>
                        <input 
                            style="width: 45px;" 
                            class="mx-auto form-control form-control-sm text-center" 
                            name="id[]" 
                            id="{{ 'id' . $loop->iteration }}" 
                            value="{{ $employee->id  }}" 
                            readonly
                        >
                    </td>

                    <td class="text-center align-middle">
                        <input 
                            style="width: 45px;" class="mx-auto form-control form-control-sm text-center" 
                            name="dias_laborados[]"
                            id="{{ 'dias_laborados' . $loop->iteration }}"
                            value="{{ $configuration->salary_period  }}"
                        >                        
                    </td>                

                    <td class="text-center align-middle">
                        <input 
                            style="width: 77px;" 
                            class="mx-auto form-control form-control-sm text-center" 
                            name="porcentaje_aumento[]" 
                            id="{{ 'porcentaje_aumento' . $loop->iteration }}" 
                            value="{{ $employee->porcentaje_aumento }}"
                            readonly
                        >
                    </td>

                    <td class="text-center align-middle">
                        <input 
                            style="width: 100px;" 
                            class="mx-auto form-control form-control-sm text-center" 
                            name="basico[]" 
                            id="{{ 'basico' . $loop->iteration }}"
                            readonly 
                        >
                    </td>

                    <td class="text-center align-middle">
                        <input 
                            style="width: 45px;" 
                            class="mx-auto form-control form-control-sm text-center" 
                            name="horas_extras[]" 
                            id="{{ 'horas_extras' . $loop->iteration }}" 
                            value="0"
                        >
                    </td>

                    <td class="text-center align-middle">
                        <input 
                            style="width: 100px;" 
                            class="mx-auto form-control form-control-sm text-center" 
                            name="total_horas_extras_diurnas[]" 
                            id="{{ 'total_horas_extras_diurnas' . $loop->iteration }}" 
                            value="0"
                            readonly
                        >
                    </td>

                    <td class="text-center align-middle">
                        <input 
                            style="width: 100px;" 
                            class="mx-auto form-control form-control-sm text-center" 
                            name="total[]" 
                            id="{{ 'total' . $loop->iteration }}" 
                            readonly
                        >
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
              <button id="calcular" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Calcular</button>
              <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Limpiar</button>
            </div>
    </form>
```

EL form se ve de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos se ven de esta manera en el request:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En en el controlador recibo los datos por medio de POST y los envio a la base de datos de la siguiente manera.

```html
public function store(Request $request)
    {        
        $employees = DB::table('users')
        ->select()
        ->whereNull('fecha_retiro')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();
        
        $uuid = Str::uuid();
        $fechaInicial = $request->fecha_inicial;
        $fechaFinal = $request->fecha_final;

        //return($request);
        
        foreach($request->id as $key => $value){
            $payroll = array(
                'uuid'=>$uuid,
                'dias_laborados'=>$request->dias_laborados[$key],
                'porcentaje_aumento'=>$request->porcentaje_aumento[$key],
                'basico'=>$request->basico[$key],
                'horas_extras'=>$request->horas_extras[$key],
                'total_horas_extras_diurnas'=>$request->total_horas_extras_diurnas[$key],
                'horas_festivas_diurnas'=>$request->horas_festivas_diurnas[$key],
                'total_horas_festivas_diurnas'=>$request->total_horas_festivas_diurnas[$key],
                'horas_extras_festivas_diurnas'=>$request->horas_extras_festivas_diurnas[$key],
                'total_horas_extras_festivas_diurnas'=>$request->total_horas_extras_festivas_diurnas[$key],
                'horas_nocturnas'=>$request->horas_nocturnas[$key],
                'total_horas_nocturnas'=>$request->total_horas_nocturnas[$key],
                'horas_extras_nocturnas'=>$request->horas_extras_nocturnas[$key],
                'total_horas_extras_nocturnas'=>$request->total_horas_extras_nocturnas[$key],
                'horas_extras_festivas_nocturnas'=>$request->horas_extras_festivas_nocturnas[$key],
                'total_horas_extras_festivas_nocturnas'=>$request->total_horas_extras_festivas_nocturnas[$key],
                'otros_recargos'=>$request->otros_recargos[$key],
                'descripcion_otros_recargos'=>$request->descripcion_otros_recargos[$key],
                'deducciones'=>$request->deducciones[$key],
                'descripcion_deducciones'=>$request->descripcion_deducciones[$key],
                'auxilio_transporte'=>$request->auxilio_transporte[$key],
                'deduccion_salud'=>$request->deduccion_salud[$key],
                'deduccion_pension'=>$request->deduccion_pension[$key],
                'total'=>$request->total[$key],
                'user_id'=>$request->id[$key],
                'fecha_inicial'=>$fechaInicial,
                'fecha_final'=>$fechaFinal
            );
            Payroll::insert($payroll);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Suena a que deberías mandar el post a una cola rabbitmq, y que un consumer de encargara de ir poco a poco haciendo el insert de cada elemento. También podrías mirar ir liberando memoria cada vez que haces un insert. Otra opción es que el listado que muestras de formularios sea paginado. Así solo mandarías como mucho los datos de trabajadores de una página.

Answer (score 0):

¿porqué la necesidad de enviar formulario? incluso si lograras solucionarlo, la cantidad de `insert` generará un `timeout`

Si de todas formas vas a guardarlos, ya generalos en la BD y modificas con `X-editable`

Otra idea es encriptarlo con `base64` el `JSON` resultante del `formulario` ; así envias un uníco valor;

**JavaScript**

```
$('#miForm').on('submit', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var jsonData=$(this).serializeArray()
        .reduce(function(a, z) { a[z.name] = z.value; return a; }, {});
    
    $.post(uri + "/save", {data: window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( jsonData)))})
   .then(res => alert("Guardado")).fail(e => alert("error"));
});
```

**PHP**

```
function save(Request $req){
    //$req->all()= {"data": "asdasdasdad..."}
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode($req->data),true);
}
```

de esta manera ya solo envias un u´nico parámetro

Answer (score 0):

es normal pensar que algo así(Tú ejemplo) pueda ser solucionado con el aumento de MB en `php.ini`. Y me incluyo al pensar que un `for` era la mejor solución para este tipo de situaciones, pero ninguna de las dos son la solución.

Entonces lo primero que debes de cambiar es:

> **que en el servidor no exista un `for` al momento de guardar los datos**, esto por un sin numero de razones que deben de ser controladas.

Entonces el `for` en tu php:

```
foreach($request->id as $key => $value){
    $payroll = array(
       'uuid'=>$uuid,
       'dias_laborados'=>$request->di...
       ...
    );
    Payroll::insert($payroll);
}
```

**Esta mal!!!**

Lo que debes de hacer es crear tu propio controlador para `Payroll` el cual debe de tener su propia función store, el cual se encargue únicamente de guardar 1 payroll a la vez:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $data=new Payroll($request->all());// en request all deberian de estar todos tus valores validados.
    return 201;//depende de ti, el valor a retornar 
}
```

**El trabajo duro estaría en el cliente**, realizando el `for` con javascript, jquery o cualquier otra librería/framework que estés utilizando. La petición debe de hacerse una a una con XMLHttpRequest, ajax, axios, fetch o cualquier otro que conozcas pero esta debe de ser asíncrona(`async`), esto te permitirá mostrar un mensaje de **GUARDANDO...**

Y hasta aquí es la primera opción, el problema con esto seria el tiempo de almacenado, y la cantidad de peticiones realizadas(podrían darse errores, aunque no en la base de datos).

La otra opción es: **no utilizar tablas**, si no un CRUD normal de laravel(te recomiendo tomar esta opcion si tu sistema web será utilizada).